# Jenkins build throwing an out of memory error

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, out-of-memory

We have Jenkins running on an ec2 instance. When doing a build, we see the following error:

```
17:29:39.149 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000007ac000000, 234881024, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
17:29:39.150 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] #

17:29:39.150 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.

17:29:39.150 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] # Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 234881024 bytes for committing reserved memory.
```

I researched on this topic and tried various settings such as increasing the heap memory, ram and PermGenSize. Here is my current memory setting on Jenkins:

```
-Xms256m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Are there any other things that I'm missing that's causing an OOM?

Comment: I suspect that the Jenkins memory is not the issue here, but the gradle process (which is run on its own jvm). Try increasing Gradle's memory (GRADLE_OPTS=-Xmx512m....) and test again.

Comment: I have the GRADLE_OPTS set to -Xmx2048m and I still have out of memory issues.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with gradle... maybe it forks a new jvm, which is what's crashing... Also - do you have enough system memory free?

Answer (score 31):

I've sold the same problem. (I have ec2, t2.micro, Ubuntu 14, Jenkins, Tomcat, Maven).
By default you **don't have swap space**.
To confirm this:

```
free -m
```

Just add some. Try with 1 GB for begin.

```
sudo fallocate -l 1G /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Check again:

```
free -m
```

For more details look [here](https://www.build-business-websites.co.uk/java-memory-allocation-failures-due-to-insufficient-swap-space/)

Comment: Worked Like a charm !!

Answer (score 8):

This is not a memory issue on JVM level, but on OS level. The JVM tries to allocate 224MB, but this amount of memory isn't available on OS level. This happens when the -Xmx settings of a JVM are larger than the amount of free memory in a system. Check the amount of free memory in the OS, and either limit the memory of your current JVM so that fits within the free memory, or try to free up memory (by limiting the amount of memory other processes use) or try out an EC2 instance with more memory.

Answer (score 0):

if you jules build failing for out of memory then follow below steps:

1. Increase memory size in manifest.yml file
   **Ex-  memory:4270 M (increase here)**
2. Add MAVEN_OPTS into config argument of jules.yml file

[image]

Enjoy :)