# Jenkins seemingly stops listening to the port 8080 on Ubuntu 16.04.4

Tags: jenkins, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed and started jenkins successfully. The problem is that after working for a while, the web interface returns "refused to connect".

After `lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`, I don't see anything listening to the port 8080.

The weird thing is `cat /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log` returns nothing.

When I run `service jenkins start` nothing happens. `service jenkins restart` on the other hand gets things back to normal.

Here is the contents of `/etc/default/jenkins`:

```
# defaults for Jenkins automation server

# pulled in from the init script; makes things easier.
NAME=jenkins

# arguments to pass to java

# Allow graphs etc. to work even when an X server is present
JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"

#JAVA_ARGS="-Xmx1024m"

# make jenkins listen on IPv4 address
#JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME/$NAME.pid

# user and group to be invoked as (default to jenkins)
JENKINS_USER=$NAME
JENKINS_GROUP=$NAME

# location of the jenkins war file
JENKINS_WAR=/usr/share/$NAME/$NAME.war

# jenkins home location
JENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/$NAME

# set this to false if you don't want Jenkins to run by itself
# in this set up, you are expected to provide a servlet container
# to host jenkins.
RUN_STANDALONE=true

# log location.  this may be a syslog facility.priority
JENKINS_LOG=/var/log/$NAME/$NAME.log
#JENKINS_LOG=daemon.info

# Whether to enable web access logging or not.
# Set to "yes" to enable logging to /var/log/$NAME/access_log
JENKINS_ENABLE_ACCESS_LOG="no"

# OS LIMITS SETUP
#   comment this out to observe /etc/security/limits.conf
#   this is on by default because http://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/commit/2fb288474e980d0e7ff9c4a3b768874835a3e92e
#   reported that Ubuntu's PAM configuration doesn't include pam_limits.so, and as a result the # of file
#   descriptors are forced to 1024 regardless of /etc/security/limits.conf
MAXOPENFILES=8192

# set the umask to control permission bits of files that Jenkins creates.
#   027 makes files read-only for group and inaccessible for others, which some security sensitive users
#   might consider benefitial, especially if Jenkins runs in a box that's used for multiple purposes.
#   Beware that 027 permission would interfere with sudo scripts that run on the master (JENKINS-25065.)
#
#   Note also that the particularly sensitive part of $JENKINS_HOME (such as credentials) are always
#   written without 'others' access. So the umask values only affect job configuration, build records,
#   that sort of things.
#
#   If commented out, the value from the OS is inherited,  which is normally 022 (as of Ubuntu 12.04,
#   by default umask comes from pam_umask(8) and /etc/login.defs

# UMASK=027

# port for HTTP connector (default 8080; disable with -1)
HTTP_PORT=8080


# servlet context, important if you want to use apache proxying
PREFIX=/$NAME

# arguments to pass to jenkins.
# --javahome=$JAVA_HOME
# --httpListenAddress=$HTTP_HOST (default 0.0.0.0)
# --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT (default 8080; disable with -1)
# --httpsPort=$HTTP_PORT
# --argumentsRealm.passwd.$ADMIN_USER=[password]
# --argumentsRealm.roles.$ADMIN_USER=admin
# --webroot=~/.jenkins/war
# --prefix=$PREFIX

JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT"
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue. I'm deploying jenkins on vultr vps with limited ram memory. I believe the limited memory is the cause. I fixed this by following this link [Jenkins build throwing an out of memory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041512/jenkins-build-throwing-an-out-of-memory-error/35682902)

```
sudo fallocate -l 1G /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Check again:

```
free -m
```

Comment: I somehow missed this answer. It's been a long time since I had this issue but I think adding more swap was, indeed, what solved it for me also. I can't mark this answer because It still may be a different issue and I'm just simply relying on my memory about how it was solved. It could mislead people with the same issue as mine. I don't think it would hurt but still. However if you're positive that these are the same issues, that's plenty enough for me, I'll take your word and mark this.